# Google Map SDK and iOS, observeValueForKeyPath issues

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xcode7

I'm following a Google MAP SDK  [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/) for iOS, almost everything is fine, but this function

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [String : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if !didFindMyLocation {
            let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
            viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
            viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true

            didFindMyLocation = true
        }
    }
```

> "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Xcode 7
Swift 2
Google Map iOS SDK

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Which tutorial, is it something we can take a look at?

Comment: @KarthikMurugesan  http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this? Updated the code for the latest version of Swift. Looks like the sample is based on older version of Swift.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
        viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
        viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true

        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple Swift version 2.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.6 clang-700.1.76)